# How to detect MySQL Server installed in a network?

Tags: mysql

I have 5 systems in a network, how can I detect which systems have MySQL server installed?

Comment: If you are asking if mysql is running on a remote box, and are not looking for nmap like answers, the default mysql port is tcp 3306.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming MySQL is running on the default port on each of the servers, just try connecting to the database "as normal" on port 3306.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL servers listen to requests on local port `3306`. A *telnet* can tell you if something answers at that location

```
telnet someserver 3306
```

However the port may be configured differently (eg `9999`). And the servers firewall may prevent any access to that port anyway (since some MySQL servers are accessed from a local application, like PHP, and thus do not need external access).